# Trouble with CUDA Memory Allocation and Access

Tags: memory, gpgpu, cuda

I am working on learning CUDA right now. I have some basic experience with MPI so I figured I'd start with some really simple vector operations. I am trying to write a parallelized dot product thing. I am either having trouble allocating/writing memory to the CUDA device, or I am not correctly bringing it back to the host (cudaMemcpy()).

```
     /*Code for a CUDA test project doing a basic dot product with doubles
     *
     *
     *
     */
      #include <stdio.h>
      #include <cuda.h>

      __global__ void GPU_parallelDotProduct(double *array_a, double *array_b, double          *dot){
          dot[0] += array_a[threadIdx.x] * array_b[threadIdx.x];
      }

     __global__ void GPU_parallelSetupVector(double *vector, int dim, int incrSize,          int start){
             if(threadIdx.x<dim){
                vector[threadIdx.x] = start + threadIdx.x * incrSize;
            }
     }

     __host__ void CPU_serialDot(double *first, double *second, double *dot, int dim){
          for(int i=0; i<dim; ++i){
             dot[0] += first[i] * second[i];
         }
      }

     __host__ void CPU_serialSetupVector(double *vector, int dim, int incrSize, int          start){
          for(int i=0; i<dim; ++i){
             vector[i] = start + i * incrSize;
         }
      }

      int main(){
     //define array size to be used
         //int i,j;
         int VECTOR_LENGTH = 8;
         int ELEMENT_SIZE  = sizeof(double);
         //arrays for dot product
         //host
         double *array_a  = (double*) malloc(VECTOR_LENGTH * ELEMENT_SIZE);
         double *array_b  = (double*) malloc(VECTOR_LENGTH * ELEMENT_SIZE);
         double *dev_dot_product = (double*) malloc(ELEMENT_SIZE);
     double host_dot_product = 0.0;

     //fill with values
         CPU_serialSetupVector(array_a, VECTOR_LENGTH, 1, 0);
     CPU_serialSetupVector(array_b, VECTOR_LENGTH, 1, 0);
     //host dot
     CPU_serialDot(array_a, array_b, &host_dot_product, VECTOR_LENGTH);

     //device
     double *dev_array_a;
     double *dev_array_b;
         double *dev_dot;

     //allocate cuda memory
     cudaMalloc((void**)&dev_array_a, ELEMENT_SIZE * VECTOR_LENGTH);
     cudaMalloc((void**)&dev_array_b, ELEMENT_SIZE * VECTOR_LENGTH);
     cudaMalloc((void**)&dev_dot,     ELEMENT_SIZE);

     //copy to from host to device
     cudaMemcpy(dev_array_a, array_a, ELEMENT_SIZE * VECTOR_LENGTH, cudaMemcpyHostToDevice);
     cudaMemcpy(dev_array_b, array_b, ELEMENT_SIZE * VECTOR_LENGTH, cudaMemcpyHostToDevice);
     cudaMemcpy(dev_dot, &dev_dot_product, ELEMENT_SIZE, cudaMemcpyHostToDevice);

     //init vectors
     //GPU_parallelSetupVector<<<1, VECTOR_LENGTH>>>(dev_array_a, VECTOR_LENGTH, 1, 0);
     //GPU_parallelSetupVector<<<1, VECTOR_LENGTH>>>(dev_array_b, VECTOR_LENGTH, 1, 0);
     //GPU_parallelSetupVector<<<1, 1>>>(dev_dot, VECTOR_LENGTH, 0, 0);
     //perform CUDA dot product
     GPU_parallelDotProduct<<<1, VECTOR_LENGTH>>>(dev_array_a, dev_array_b, dev_dot);

    //get computed product back to the machine
    cudaMemcpy(dev_dot, dev_dot_product, ELEMENT_SIZE, cudaMemcpyDeviceToHost);

     FILE *output = fopen("test_dotProduct_1.txt", "w");
     fprintf(output, "HOST CALCULATION: %f \n", host_dot_product);
     fprintf(output, "DEV  CALCULATION: %f \n", dev_dot_product[0]);
     fprintf(output, "PRINTING DEV ARRAY VALS: ARRAY A\n");
     for(int i=0; i<VECTOR_LENGTH; ++i){
         fprintf(output, "value %i: %f\n", i, dev_array_a[i]);
     }

     free(array_a);
     free(array_b);
     cudaFree(dev_array_a);
         cudaFree(dev_array_b);
     cudaFree(dev_dot);

     return(0);
     }
```

Here is an example output:

```
    HOST CALCULATION: 140.000000 
    DEV  CALCULATION: 0.000000 
    PRINTING DEV ARRAY VALS: ARRAY A
    value 0: -0.000000
    value 1: 387096841637590350000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000.000000
    value 2: -9188929998371095800000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000.000000
    value 3: 242247762331550610000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000.000000
    value 4: -5628111589595087500000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000.000000
    value 5: 395077289052074410000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000.000000
    value 6: 0.000000
    value 7: -13925691551991564000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000.000000
```

Answer (score 4):

There are two problems I can see:

1. Your GPU dot product contains a memory race here:

   ```
    dot[0] += array_a[threadIdx.x] * array_b[threadIdx.x];
   ```

   This is unsafe - every thread in the block will attempt to write/overwrite the same memory location with its result. The programming model makes no guarantees about what will happen in a case when multiple threads try and write a different value to the same piece of memory.
2. Your Code is attempting to directly access a device memory location
   in the host when you are printing out the vector. I am surprised
   that the code does not produce a segfault or protection error.
   `dev_array_a` is not directly accessible by the host, it is a
   pointer in GPU memory. You must use a device to host copy to a valid
   host location if you want to examine the contents of `dev_array_a`.

The suggestion about error checking made in another answer is also a very good point. Every API call returns a status and you should check the status of all calls you make to confirm that no errors or faults occur at runtime.

Comment: Yeah, I realize that now. I'll have to be more careful. I was thinking that might have been the problem. Is there anything like MPI_Reduce() for CUDA? Or would it be best to write each value into an third array and then condense this third array? Now I'm wondering if this would even be faster, I'm back in linear time now.

Comment: The SDK contains a really useful reduction example and white paper that is worth looking at. Alternatively, the Thrust template library, which ships with recent versions of the CUDA toolkit has a C++ implementation of a parallel reduction with works on an STL like vector class which hides most of the device memory management and reduces your example down to about a dozen lines of code.

Answer (score 3):

It's a good idea to check the status of CUDA runtime calls like cudaMalloc, cudaMemcpy and kernel launches. You can do the following after every such call, or wrap this in some kind of a macro and wrap the CUDA runtime calls in the macro.

```
if (cudaSuccess != cudaGetLastError())
    printf( "Error!\n" );
```

Now, I am not sure if this is your problem, but doing this can get the obvious out of the way.

Comment: I implemented the code you posted. It throws on every CUDA call. Is there something I am missing with setting up CUDA or my card?

Comment: What versions of CUDA driver and compiler are you using? It's always a good idea to get the most recent versions from http://developer.nvidia.com/cuda-downloads